# Project Euler # 53 Combinatoric selections in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, programming-challenge

There are exactly ten ways of selecting three from five, 12345:

123, 124, 125, 134, 135, 145, 234, 235, 245, and 345

In combinatorics, we use the notation, 5C3=10.

In general, nCr = n! / r! (n−r)!, where r≤n, n! = n × (n−1) × ... × 3 × 2 × 1, and 0! = 1.

It is not until n = 23, that a value exceeds one-million: 23C10 = 1144066.

How many, not necessarily distinct, values of nCr for 1≤n≤100, are greater than one-million?

```
from time import time
from math import factorial


def combinations(n, r):
    """Assumes n, r a set of numbers and r number of numbers to choose from n.
    returns number of combinations."""
    return factorial(n) // (factorial(r) * factorial(n - r))


def generate_combinations(n_range, minimum):
    """generates non-distinct combinations in range n_range inclusive that exceed the minimum."""
    for n in range(1, n_range + 1):
        for r in range(1, n):
            combination = combinations(n, r)
            if combination > minimum:
                yield 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    START_TIME = time()
    print(sum(generate_combinations(100, 10**6)))
    print(f'Time: {time() - START_TIME} seconds.')
```

Comment: Project Euler problems are typically part coding and part thinking through the constraints of the problem, which can save a lot of compute time. For example, nCr has a consistent shape with a symmetry to it. I would suggest looking at whether you can use that shape to predict which runs of numbers are all high or all low.

Comment: I assume that you successfully solved PE#53? Did you have a look at the “overview for problem 53” document? 13 pages full of performance tips.

Comment: @ Martin No not really, can you post a link or something?

Comment: The link is at the bottom of https://projecteuler.net/problem=53. It becomes visible as soon as you submit a correct solution. There is also a link to a discussion thread where you can see how other people solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expensive way to calculate combinations:

> ```
> def combinations(n, r):
>     return factorial(n) // (factorial(r) * factorial(n - r))
> ```

Observe that \$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}\$ cancels out to a large degree:

$$
\frac{n · (n-1) ⋯ (n-r+1)}{r!}·\frac{(n-r) ⋯ 1}{(n-r) ⋯ 1}
$$
Now, if we expand *r*!, we get
$$
\frac{n · (n-1) ⋯ (n-r+1)}{1 · 2 ⋯ r}
$$
Now, *n(n-1)* must be an exact multiple of 2, and *n(n-1)(n-2)* must be an exact multiple of 2✕3, etc, so we can compute ⁿCᵣ using relatively small integers (especially if we ensure that *r* is smaller than *n-r* by swapping if not):

```
def combinations(n, r):
    """Return the number of sets of size r which can be drawn from n items
       without replacement."""
    if r > n - r:
        r = n - r
    c = 1
    for d in range(r):
        c = c * (n - d) // (d + 1)
    return c
```

Surprisingly, this turns out to be slower than the original code using `math.factorial()` here.  But we can make it more readable by using `math.comb()` directly, for the same performance as the original.

---

It should be clear that if \$^nC_r > k\$, then \$^{n+1}C_r > k\$, and if also \$r+1 <= n-r\$, then \$^nC_{r+1} > k\$.  This is something we know just by looking at Pascal's Triangle.

That means that for a given *n*, if we find the transition value for *r*, we know instantly how many *r* to count without testing them all, and have a good starting point for the next *n*.

That gets us to this function, which effectively traces the boundary of the inequality through Pascal's Triangle:

```
def generate_combinations(n_range, minimum):
    """Count how many ⁿCᵣ exceed minimum for all n up to n_range, inclusive."""
    r = 1
    for n in range(n_range, 1, -1):
        while math.comb(n, r) <= minimum and r <= n // 2:
            r += 1
        if r > n // 2:        # no qualifying values from n or smaller
            break
        yield n - 2 * r + 1   # count the range r to n-r
```

On my system, that runs about 100 times faster than the question code, and I expect it to scale better as `n_range` increases.

Answer (score 0):

just a little hack if you want a more fast solution,
can become faster if consider the similarity of the nCr and nC(n-r)

```
dic=[1]

for i in range(1,101):
    val =dic[-1]*i
    dic.append(val)


def choose(n,r):
    sol = dic[n]//(dic[n-r]*dic[r])
    return sol

def func(maxi, valu): 
    count = 0
    for i in range(2,maxi+1):
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            val = choose(i,j)
            if  val>valu:
                count+=1         
    return count


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from time import time
    START_TIME = time()
    print(func(100, 10**6))
    print(f'Time: {time() - START_TIME} seconds.')
```

just store all the value of factorial of a number upto 100 in dict and then process

update suggested by  @AJNeufeld , using list to store data than dictonary

Comment: Only the last value of list `l` is ever used, so this list could be replaced by a scalar variable.  Ie) `val = 1` outside the for-loop, and `val *= i` inside the for-loop.  Why waste time with a dictionary, when list indexing is way faster?  And `dic` is a meaningless name; how about `factorial` instead?  `val = 1; factorial = [1]; for i in range(1, 101): val *= i; factorial.append(val)`.  But this is still the wrong approach if you want speed, which you do since you are going through the effort of timing the code.

Comment: you are right, using list will do it faster, then adding the dictionary? if this is wrong approach, then how do we speed it more fast ?

Comment: `func` is also a lousy name.  You can go from an O(n^2) algorithm to an O(n) algorithm by starting at C(100,0) and incrementing `r`; if you exceed 1e6, decrement `n`.  You only need to keep track of the boundary between the greater than 1e6 values and the less than 1e6 values.